# Переделать скрипт на perl для pipe

Tags: perl, io

Имеется скрипт на perl, который обрабатывает строки из `in.txt` в `out.txt`, что жестко прописано в скрипте. Можно переделать скрипт так, чтобы вместо указания входного и выходного файлов был стандартный stdin и stdout чтобы воткнуть его в трубу?
По всей видимости исправить требуется следующий строки (прошу прощения, я в perl вообще ничего не смыслю, прошу помощи):

```
01 my $fileSrc = '**in.txt**';
02 open my $fhSrc, $fileSrc or die "Not open $fileSrc: $!";
03
04 my $fileDest = '**out.txt**';
05 open(my $fhDest, '>>', $fileDest) or die "Not open file $fileDest: $!";
06
07 close $fhSrc;
08 close $fhDest;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заменить открытия файлов. Первый:

```
open my $fhSrc, '<-' or die '...';
```

И второй:

```
open my $fhDest, '>-' or die '...';
```

Comment: А строки 01 и 04 вообще убрать? или переделать их `01 my $fileSrc = '<-';` `04 my $fileDest = '>-';` ??

Comment: @Bl0wfish Убрать. Только и тексты в `die` поменять, там эти переменные интерполируются.

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
while( <> ) {
 chomp; # если надо, см. ниже
 my $rc = foo( $_ ); 
 print $rc if defined $rc; 
 # не забыть про перевод строки - здесь или в foo()
}

sub foo 
{
  # вернуть undef в случае ошибки, или обработаную строку
}
```